# What generates the SQL in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have tried to find this answer but cannot. What is generating the underlying SQL when using EF? Is it EF or the provider you are using? Also, is there any way to provide hints in order to change the way the SQL is generated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework takes your LINQ queries and examines them using Expression Trees.

The provider then uses those Expression Trees to generate the appropriate SQL statements.

MSDN has a very good explanation of [Expression Trees and how they work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can generate "hints" is through the way you write your LINQ statements.  The Provider is what generates the SQL.

If you decide you want to write your own proivider check out [re-linq](http://relinq.codeplex.com/).  [White paper on re-linq](http://www.re-motion.org/download/re-linq.pdf) (explains a lot about what it is..